# Insert two fields in Word 2010 page header using VBA

Tags: vba, header, field, word-2010

I am trying to insert two fields in a page header. I am able to insert them at the current selection (see code below), but I would prefer not having to select the page header before inserting the fields. Can this be done?

```
Sub insertFields()
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCPROPERTY LastSavedTime ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FileName", PreserveFormatting:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the section of the document to place the field in as well as the type of header  (`wdHeaderFooterPrimary`, `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` or `wdHeaderFooterEvenPages`) you can use this code:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DOCPROPERTY LastSavedTime ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

**Additional Information in response to comment**

You can use the `Collapse` method, which places the insertion point at the start or end position of a range, to insert multiple fields within the header. Add appropriate additional code to insert spaces, formatting or carriage returns:

```
myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FileName", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Comment: That gives me _one_ field. However, duplicating the second line does _not_ give me a second field. Of course, this must be possible.

Comment: Please see the additional information I've added in regards to the `Collapse` method.

Comment: The code below does not seem to add the text " hi " at all. Experimenting with different orders of the rows gives me the text " hi " at the beginning or end of the header. But never where it should be, in the middle of the fields.
`Set myRange = s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range :   
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=True :   
myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd :   
myRange.Text = " hi " :   
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME", PreserveFormatting:=True`

Comment: @FredrikP, let's review your actions. You posted a question about inserting fields in headers. I answered it. You asked for additional information. I supplied it. You marked my answer as correct and left a comment thanking me. You then deleted your comment, took away your check mark that my answer was correct and subsequently, in your comment above, ask a completely different (and unclear) question about how to insert text in a range within or between fields. This is not how Stack Overflow works. If your question is answered, mark it correct and then post a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to this. I have marked the question as answered again. Will post a new question presently.

Comment: I have seen users criticised elsewhere for posting questions that were too similar.

Comment: And that criticism is often warranted because one of the tenets Stack Overflow is based on is the notion that those asking questions should be concurrently engaged in the process of self-teaching. If two questions from the same person are similar it usually implies that the questioner did not take the principles revealed in the first answer and, with additional research, apply them to a similar problem. If the user does not have the ability to do so, he/she is probably more in the need of general education on a topic, which is beyond the scope of a question and answer site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: In a perhaps naive hope that such criticism does not (at least not wholly) apply  to me, I have now posted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747261/inserting-text-and-fields-in-word-2010-header-without-using-select). (In case you might inclined to answer also that one.)