# Add page number to a Word document using Python

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

Is there a way to add page numbers to the lower right corner of a Word document using Python win32com? I am able to add headers and footers, but I can't find a way to add page numbers in the format PageNumber of TotalPages (for example: 1 of 5)

Below is the code to add centered headers and footers to a page

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch as MakeDoc
filename = name + '.doc'
WordDoc = MakeDoc("Word.Application")
WordDoc = WordDoc.Documents.Add()
WordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Text = name
WordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Text = filename
WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this one so that others with the same issue (i.e. me) can figure it out as well

Comment: To insert page numbers use the following statements:

`WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.Add(2,True)`
`WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.NumberStyle = 57`
However, the format of the number is -PageNumber- instead of the one I was looking for, but I'm fine with it anyways

Comment: Thanks, can you post and documentation for that?

Comment: Sure, the documentation for the adding the page numbers is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178815(v=office.12).aspx) and the one for the number style is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237910(v=office.12).aspx). Enjoy

Comment: You should post an answer not a comment; as it is your question will appear open (unanswered) in SO search lists.

Comment: I tried yesterday, but I could not do so because I don't have enough permissions or I had to wait many hours to do it

Comment: The answer is there now

Answer (score 4):

To insert page numbers use the following statements:

```
WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.Add(2,True)
WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.NumberStyle = 57
```

However, the format of the page number is -page number-. Documentation for inserting the page number is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178815%28v=office.12%29.aspx), and the one for the number style is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237910%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was banging my head against a wall trying to figure out the same thing and ended up working out a solution that's rather ugly, but gets the job done. Note that I had to redefine `activefooter` after inserting `wdFieldPage` or else the resulting footer would look like `of  12` rather than `1 of 2`.

[The answer to this vba question was helpful when I was trying to figure out the formatting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747261/inserting-text-and-fields-in-word-2010-header-without-using-select)

I'm using Python 3.4, testdocument.doc is just an existing .doc file with some random text spread across two pages and no existing footer.

```
w = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")          
w.Visible = 0
adoc = w.Documents.Open("C:\\temp1\\testdocument.doc")

activefooter = adoc.Sections(1).Footers(win32com.client.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
activefooter.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = win32com.client.constants.wdAlignParagraphRight
activefooter.Collapse(0)
activefooter.Fields.Add(activefooter,win32com.client.constants.wdFieldPage)
activefooter = adoc.Sections(1).Footers(win32com.client.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range 
activefooter.Collapse(0)
activefooter.InsertAfter(Text = ' of ')
activefooter.Collapse(0)
activefooter.Fields.Add(activefooter,win32com.client.constants.wdFieldNumPages)  
adoc.Save()
adoc.Close()
w.Quit()
```